# How to access Build Setting Constants like $(PROJECT_DIR) in swift?

Tags: swift, perfect

I am working on Server side swift (Perfect 2.0). Is there a way to get access to Xcode's build setting variable "$(PROJECT_DIR)" or "$(SRCROOT)" with out using any CocoaTouch frameworks. i.e CoreFoundation. ?

what actually I want is to access my project's root directory from code. but Using NSBundle won't work because its not CocoaTouch

Comment: Why do you need to access it at runtime? And you can use foundation if you want and you're going to in the server on Mac OS

Comment: @Wain : Now i know that i don't. when i posted this question i didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Perfect's file and directory handling.
https://www.perfect.org/docs/file.html